# Web development transition from MAMP to Docker

Tags: php, mysql, web, docker, boot2docker

I am new to Docker and I am having a hard time applying its core technology to my present web development. Using MAMP, you just need to download the app, put your PHP/HTML files on /htdocs, start servers, then go to http://localhost:8888/ to see your webapp. Now, using docker, I’m wondering how can I do the same. What I’ve done so far is to pull http, php and mysql images from the Docker Hub.

1. How can I link these three images together to make them work? Or How should I run them simultaneously?
2. Where should I put the /htdocs or how can I access it?
3. MAMP has a phpMyAdmin for database access, does Docker has something like this?

I’m working on a Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.1) with boot2docker v1.4.1 and VirtualBox 4.3.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How can I link these three images together to make them work? Or How should I run them simultaneously?

Use [fig](http://fig.sh) to define and link containers.

> 2. Where should I put the /htdocs or how can I access it?

This depends solely on your container configuration. You may try [PHP with Apache](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/php/) from DockerHub. See the docs for an explanation where to put your files.

> 3. MAMP has a phpMyAdmin for database access, does Docker has something like this?

Sure, a Docker container ;) [search DockerHub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=phpmyadmin&s=stars)

Comment: addon: I am working on a [PHP application template](http://phundament.com) which could give you some ideas, it also runs locally with XAMP & co.

Answer (score 7):

You can now use `docker-compose` and a docker-compose.yml file to accomplish the same thing as fig.

Finding containers for each service and linking them together isn't the easiest thing. The docker-compose file from [The damp github project](https://github.com/gilbitron/damp) (pasted below for posterity) is a good start for how to get the apache, php, and mysql services all running with a `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` command.

```
proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports: ['80:80']
    volumes: ['/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro']
    environment: [DEFAULT_HOST=damp.dev]
database:
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    ports: ['3306:3306']
    environment: [MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password]
phpmyadmin:
    image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
    links: ['database:mysql']
    environment: [MYSQL_USERNAME=root, MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password, VIRTUAL_HOST=phpmyadmin.damp.dev]
damp:
    image: httpd
    volumes: ['~/damp/damp:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs']
    environment: [VIRTUAL_HOST=damp.dev]
```

Once you do that _and put an entry for `damp.dev 127.0.0.1` in your hosts file, anything you mount in ~/damp/damp (per that second to last line) will be put in the htdocs of the docker container and served up on damp.dev/[whatever].

damp is just the first example I found poking around on how to replicate MAMP with docker. The most important thing to note is that you can use `docker-compose` instead of `fig`. [Compose is based directly on the Fig codebase and is backwards-compatible with Fig applications.](https://blog.docker.com/2015/02/announcing-docker-compose/)